# Getting output from array which has been loaded from file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm trying to get the contents of a file to print out after it has been loaded into an array. I'm getting the first entry printed, but the rest are all output as 0. I feel like I need to put another loop somewhere but I'm not sure where it would work best.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct plane //strcutre of plane data to use
{
   string name;
    string direction;
    int id;
    int coordX;
    int coordY;
    int height;
    int speed;

};

void populate (plane planeArray[], int n )
{
    string name, direction;
    int id, coordX, coordY, height, speed, i, c;
    ifstream infile;                              //declare input file stream
    infile.open("plane_data.txt");                //opens file
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "File cannot be reached";          //checks for invalid file path
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        getline(infile, planeArray[i].name);
        infile >> planeArray[i].id;
        infile >> planeArray[i].coordX;
        infile >> planeArray[i].coordY;
        infile >> planeArray[i].height;
        infile >> planeArray[i].speed;
        getline(infile, planeArray[i].direction);
    }

    infile.close();

}

void text_display( plane planeArray[5])
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        cout << planeArray[i].name << endl;
        cout << planeArray[i].direction << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].id << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].coordX << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].coordY << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].height << endl;;
        cout << planeArray[i].speed << endl;;
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    plane planeArray[N] = {};

    populate( planeArray, N );
    text_display( planeArray);
}
```

Here is the content contained in the file:

```
Airbus A380 
123456 
123 300 
25000 
400 
north

Boeing-747 
140
234567 
30000 
450 
north west

Cessna-404-Titan 
345678 
145 
29000 
400 
south

Sukhoi-Superjet-100 
456789 
120 
28000 
300 
south west

Lockheed-Jetstar 
567890 
270 
20000 
500 
east
```

And here is the output I get when I run the code:

```
Airbus A380

123456
123
300
25000
400

north

0
0
0
0
0



0
0
0
0
0



0
0
0
0
0


Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.090 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Any help is much appreciated! (Also, if you can tell me how to get rid of the blank lines around the first and last entry in the printed data, that'd be a nice bonus.)

Cheers

Comment: Between each loop iteration, you should check that the stream's is not in an error state;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a blank line between blocks in the file, that you ignore.

After reading the first block and moving to the second one the file position is still at the front of the empty line. Your reads for the second block are then one line off from the actual data.

This means you are reading an empty line to `planeArray[1].name` and then you try to read from the line `Boeing-747` into `planeArray[1].id` which will fail because the format doesn't match for `int`. At this point the stream goes into error state and doesn't read anything anymore after that.

This can be fixed by adding an additional `getline` to a dummy string at the end of the loop.

Your file is also missing the second coordinate for all blocks except the first one, which will result in a similar problem.

Comment: As a quick fix I removed the blank lines between each section of data however I am still getting the same output. For the dummy line, would it simply be another addition to the array and a getline to the empty line between blocks of data?

Comment: @MichaelDelahorne Added another problem to my answer. With the dummy variable I simply mean something like `string s; getline(infile,s);`. Then `s` is the dummy because you won't actually need its value for anything.

Answer (score 1):

there is a space in your x-coordinate for your airbus. This way

```
infile >> planeArray[i].coordX;
infile >> planeArray[i].coordY;
```

reads twice from the same line (123 300)
so you are out of sync with the structure of the file you are reading.

You have two options:

- ensure your syntax is correct (just remove the space and move on)
- add extra checks to ensure you read a name or a number, ....

Comment: Silly mistake on my part. I have now fixed that and added any missing data and I am still getting the same output however.

Comment: same for the white lines between subsequent items: either add an extra "getline" or remove them from your textfile

Comment: I've removed the blank lines and the output is still the same for some reason.

Comment: in your program you read 1 name, 5 number, 1 name. In your textfile you only have 4 successive numbers. Just conform your textfile exactly to what you're trying to read